# Can't get the 'Follow' button to work with Acts_As_Follower

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm using Acts_as_follower in a wishlist app I'm working on. I think it should be working, but the button to actually follow another user is not. The follow button is in my user index view, and I can see it there, but it doesn't respond to being clicked. Any help would be appreciated. Here's my code:

index.html.erb

```
<div class="container">
  <% @users.each do |u| %>
    <div class="col-sm-8 col-lg-4">
      <div id="gifts">
        <div class="box panel panel-default">
          <h2><%= link_to u.name, u %></h2>
          <p>
          <table align="center" margin="5">
            <tr>
              <th style="padding-right: 10px"><%= button_to "View Wishlist", u, method: :get, class: "btn btn-primary" %></th>
              <th>
                <% if current_user.following?(u) %>
                  <%= form_tag user_unfollow_path(user_id: u.id), method: :delete, remote: true do %>
                    <%= button_tag 'unfollow', class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
                  <% end %>
                <% else %>
                  <%= form_tag user_follow_path(user_id: u.id), method: :post, remote: true do %>
                    <%= button_tag 'follow', class: 'btn btn-success' %>
                  <% end %>
                <% end %>
              </th>
            </tr>
          </table>
      <p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

followers_controller.rb

```
class FollowersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  respond_to :js


  def create
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    current_user.follow(@user)
  end

  def destroy
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    current_user.stop_following(@user)
  end
end
```

users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @gifts = @user.gifts
  end

  def index
    @users = User.all

    if params[:search]
     @users = User.search(params[:search]).order("created_at DESC")
    else
     @users = User.all.order("created_at DESC")
    end

  end

  def create
     @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
     current_user.follow(@user)
   end

  def destroy
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    current_user.stop_following(@user)
  end

private
  def get_gifts
    @gifts = Gift.find(params[:id])
  end


end
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users

  resources :users, only: [:index] do
  post :follow, :to => 'followers#create'
  delete :unfollow, :to => 'followers#destroy'
  end

  resources :gifts
  resources :wishlists

  get 'wishlists/index'
  get '/wishlists', :to => 'wishlists#index'
  get '/users/:id', :to => 'users#show', :as => :user
  get '/users', :to => 'users#index'


  root "gifts#index"
end
```

user.rb (model)

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

 acts_as_follower
 acts_as_followable

  has_many :gifts
  belongs_to :wishlist

  def self.search(search)
    where("name ILIKE ?", "%#{search}%")
  end
end
```

routes:

```
C:\Sites\gladlygift>rake routes
                  Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                        Controller#A
tion
        new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)           devise/sessi
ns#new
            user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)           devise/sessi
ns#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)          devise/sessi
ns#destroy
           user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)          devise/passw
rds#create
       new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)      devise/passw
rds#new
      edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)     devise/passw
rds#edit
                         PATCH  /users/password(.:format)          devise/passw
rds#update
                         PUT    /users/password(.:format)          devise/passw
rds#update
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)            devise/regis
rations#cancel
       user_registration POST   /users(.:format)                   devise/regis
rations#create
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)           devise/regis
rations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)              devise/regis
rations#edit
                         PATCH  /users(.:format)                   devise/regis
rations#update
                         PUT    /users(.:format)                   devise/regis
rations#update
                         DELETE /users(.:format)                   devise/regis
rations#destroy
             user_follow POST   /users/:user_id/follow(.:format)   followers#cr
ate
           user_unfollow DELETE /users/:user_id/unfollow(.:format) followers#de
troy
                   users GET    /users(.:format)                   users#index
                   gifts GET    /gifts(.:format)                   gifts#index
                         POST   /gifts(.:format)                   gifts#create
                new_gift GET    /gifts/new(.:format)               gifts#new
               edit_gift GET    /gifts/:id/edit(.:format)          gifts#edit
                    gift GET    /gifts/:id(.:format)               gifts#show
                         PATCH  /gifts/:id(.:format)               gifts#update
                         PUT    /gifts/:id(.:format)               gifts#update
                         DELETE /gifts/:id(.:format)               gifts#destro

               wishlists GET    /wishlists(.:format)               wishlists#in
ex
                         POST   /wishlists(.:format)               wishlists#cr
ate
            new_wishlist GET    /wishlists/new(.:format)           wishlists#ne

           edit_wishlist GET    /wishlists/:id/edit(.:format)      wishlists#ed
t
                wishlist GET    /wishlists/:id(.:format)           wishlists#sh
w
                         PATCH  /wishlists/:id(.:format)           wishlists#up
ate
                         PUT    /wishlists/:id(.:format)           wishlists#up
ate
                         DELETE /wishlists/:id(.:format)           wishlists#de
troy
         wishlists_index GET    /wishlists/index(.:format)         wishlists#in
ex
                         GET    /wishlists(.:format)               wishlists#in
ex
                    user GET    /users/:id(.:format)               users#show
                         GET    /users(.:format)                   users#index
                    root GET    /                                  gifts#index
```

Comment: Is there anything in JS console when you try to click the button? Does it have `disabled` attribute in DOM element? Finally, since it is an AJAX call, what is there in the Response tab in Dev tools for the request if you click on this button?

Comment: This is what I see in the console section of Dev tools (I'm very new so maybe I'm looking at the wrong thing) Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: If I look at dev tools in firefox, under the JS section, in Response, I get the following:       TypeError in FollowersController#create

no implicit conversion of nil into String
Extracted source (around line #24):

#22             PGconn.quote_ident(schema) << SEPARATOR << PGconn.quote_ident(identifier)

Comment: Can you paste output from `rake routes | grep follow`?

Comment: Sure, I just added it to my question.

Comment: Have you tried this: https://github.com/tcocca/acts_as_follower/issues/79#issuecomment-249397340 ? This GH Issue is about the same problem that you have.

Comment: Wow, that worked! Thank you so much!